# CommandLineToArgvW equivalent on Linux

Tags: c, linux, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for an equivalent function to Windows' [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391.aspx).

I have a string, which I want to break up *exactly* the way bash does it, with all the corner cases - i.e. taking into account single and double quotes, backslashes, etc., so splitting `a b "c'd" "\"e\"f" "g\\" h 'i"j'` would result into:

```
a
b
c'd
"e"f
g\
h
i"j
```

Since such a function already exist and is used by the OS/bash, I'm assuming there's a way to call it, or at least get its source code, so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

**Edit**

To answer why I need it, it has nothing to do with spawning child processes. I want to make a program that searches text, watching for multiple regular expressions to be true in whatever order. But all the regular expressions would be input in the same text field, so I need to break them up.

Comment: The first thought that occurs to me is: do you need to? What are you using this for?

Comment: I'm trying to make a text search program, where you input multiple regular expressions in the same field. Instead of inputting them at separate boxes, you input all at once, but they are broken up according to those rules. Since backslashes and special characters matter in regex, I need them to be taken into account.

Comment: That might not be the best way to handle multiple regexes since regexes often contain spaces and quotes. I would be confused having regexes parsed with shell quoting rules. Perhaps you can have them delimited by slashes like many languages do, e.g. `/foo bar.*/ /baz*/`.

Comment: Yes, but most commonly (like 99%) the regexes would in fact be plain words separated by spaces. The regex is just a very advanced option. It would be much more natural for the most common case to just type words separated by spaces.

Comment: @satuon You probably don't want it to behave "exactly like bash", because bash does it in a fairly surprising way (for example, you can't use backslash inside of single quotes to quote a single quote). You say that such a function already exists, but as I mention, Bash implements something that does a lot more than just string splitting. You are probably going to want to just implement the parser yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU/Linux is made of [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) and [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is free software, so you can get the source code and improve it (and you should publish your improving patches under GPL license).

But there is no common library doing that, because it is the role of the shell to expand the command line to arguments to the [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall (which then go to the `main` of the invoked program).

<sup>(this was different in MS-DOS, where the called program had to expand its command line)</sup>

The function [wordexp(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) is close to what you may want.

You may want to study the source code of simpler shells, e.g. download [sash-3.7.tar.gz](http://members.tip.net.au/~dbell/programs/sash-3.7.tar.gz)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to expand a string exactly the way Bash does, you will need to run Bash. Remember, Bash does parameter expansion, command substitution, and the like. If it really needs to act exactly like Bash, just call Bash itself.

```
FILE *f = popen("bash", "r+");
fprintf(f, "echo %s", your_string);
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f);
pclose(f);
```

Note that real code would need to handle errors and possibly allocating a bigger buffer if your original is not large enough.

Given your updated requirements, it sounds like you don't want to parse it exactly like Bash does. Instead, you just want to parse space-separated strings with quoting and escaping. I would recommend simply implementing this yourself; I do not know of any off the shelf library that will parse strings exactly the way that you specify. You don't have to write it entirely by hand; you can use a lexical scanner generator like [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) or [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) for this purpose.

Comment: I'll try, but this kind of string parsing usually has many corner cases, which means many potential bugs. That's why I wanted to use proven code.

Comment: @satuon You don't have to do it entirely by hand. You could use a parser generator. For this simple task, [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/), a state machine generator, would probably work well.